# Character Encoding Mismatch

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, mojibake

My scripts are definitely saved in UTF-8. I'm instantiating PDO with `"{$this->engine}:host={$this->host};dbname={$this->name};charset=UTF-8"`. My tables use InnoDB and are collated using utf8_general_ci. My pages are sent either with the `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` header or the `<meta>` equivalent.

When using PDO to store a € character originating either from HTTP input or a string literal in the source code, I'm left with `c3 a2 e2 80 9a c2 ac` according to MySQL Workbench 5.2. Retrieving this from the database and displaying it on the page works fine. Yet in phpMyAdmin and Workbench, I see `â‚¬`.

When using these two tools to store a €, I'm left with `e2 82 ac`, which is apparently the correct UTF-8 representation, but if I try to retrieve and then output this with PHP, � is displayed.

My question is, from where does this discrepancy arise and is it possible to have my web pages and database tools both work flawlessly?

Comment: Strange, sounds like you're doing everything right. Are you 1000% sure your DB connection is UTF-8? Can you send a `SET NAMES utf8;` query just to make sure?

Comment: And is your browser ignoring the encoding? The charset is advisory and will be ignored by the browser if you've configured it to do so. Is the behaviour the same in different browsers? On different machines?

Comment: For good measure, make sure your PHP script is configured to use UTF-8. If PHP is doing on-the-fly character conversions because it thinks files need to use another ISO character table, this might account for what you're seeing. `ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The charset directive in the DSN actually applies to MSSQL. I simply needed to execute `SET NAMES`. Sorry about that.

I achieved that thus:

```
parent::__construct("{$this->engine}:host={$this->host};dbname={$this->name}",
                    $this->user, $this->password,
                    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"));
```

Answer (score 0):

simply, convert € to an html entity &euro; for the superfix (but you may get the issue with other special chars)

the other side of the problem (and more specifically) is check the mysql [character_set_server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_server) and the most common cause [character_set_client](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_client) - seeAlso: [connection charsets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html)

also, it's important to note that the meta equiv makes no difference, you need to *always* set the header('Content-Type: ...)

Answer (score 0):

Since your HTML page is correct, it seems that you're storing the correct data in the database.

`â‚¬` is the UTF-8 encoding of the Euro sign misinterpreted as windows-1252.  It appears that your Windows tools use "ANSI" encoding instead of the database encoding.